# Why can't I store a regexp in a variable?

Tags: regex, perl

Given the following code,

```
my $string = "foo";
my $regex = s/foo/bar/;
$string =~ $regex;
print $string, "\n";
```

I would have expected the output to be `bar`, however it is `foo`. Why is that the case, and how can I solve that problem?

Note that in my actual case, the regex is more complicated, and I actually want to store several of them in a hash (so I can write something like `$string =~ $rules{$key}`).

Comment: save it as string...

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! It would have helped here.

Comment: `s/foo/bar/` is not a regexp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for substitution, not only the regex part so I guess compiled regex (`qr//`) is not what you're looking for,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "foo";
my $regex = sub { $_[0] =~ s/foo/bar/ };
$regex->($string);
print $string, "\n";
```

Your statement

```
my $regex = s/foo/bar/
```

is equivalent to

```
my $regex = $_ =~ s/foo/bar/
```

`s///` returns the number of substitutions made, or it returns false (specifically, the empty string). So `$regex` is now `''` or `1` (it could be more if the `/g` modifier was in effect) and

```
$string =~ $regex
```

is doing `'foo' =~ //` or `'foo' =~ /1/` depending on what `$_` contained originally.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good solution. But I'd still like to know why my original code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* store a regex pattern in a variable but, in your example, the regex is just `foo`, and there is a lot more going on than just that pattern

The statement `s/foo/bar/` is more complex than it seems -- it is a fully-fledged *statement* that applies a regex pattern to a *target string* and substitutes a *replacement string* if the pattern is found. In this case the target string is the default variable `$_` and the replacement string is `foo`. You could think of it as a call to a subroutine

```
substitute($_, 'foo', 'bar')
```

and the regex pattern is only the second parameter

What you can do is store a *regex pattern*. The regex part of that substitution is `foo`, and you can say

```
my $pattern = qr/foo/;

s/$pattern/bar/;
```

But you really should explain the problem that you're trying to solve so that we can help you better

Comment: Well, as stated, the problem was to store replacement regexes in a hash. `s/$pattern/bar/` hardcodes the replacement part. Storing it in a separate variable doesn't work if the replacement pattern uses match references (like `\1`).

Comment: @celtschk: There is no such thing as a *replacement regex*. You should give an example of what you would like to do. Just complaining about `s///` won't get you answers. Also, the replacement string shouldn't contain `\1` if you mean to use the first capture. `\1` is the character at code point 1 -- the Start of Header control character

Answer (score 1):

In the assignment, you need to tell Perl not to evaluate the regular expression but just to keep it.  This is what [qr](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) is for.

But you can't do this with whole substitutions, which is why Сухой27 suggests using a subroutine.

Comment: This isn't an answer, and should be a comment on the cited solution

Comment: It *is* an answer: 1) it answers why the given code doesn't work, which is a specific question  2) it answers why Сухой27's solution is necessary.